# how to display all rows in database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

how to display all rows in database in android.in the following code it is displaying only the last row in database table.please help me.

```
            public void dynamicLayout(String sfixed_AssetDescription ) {


        LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);

        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fixed_asset_dlayout, null);

        TextView dfixed_AssetID = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_AssetID);
        TextView dfixed_AssetDescription = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_AssetDescription);
        TextView dfixed_SuppliersName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_SuppliersName);
        TextView dfixed_Makemodelotherspec = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_Makemodelotherspec);
        TextView dfixed_PO_no = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_PO_no);
        TextView dfixed_PO_Date = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_PO_Date);
        TextView dfixed_Bill_No = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_Bill_No);
        TextView dfixed_qty = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_qty);
        TextView dfixed_Dateputtouse = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_Dateputtouse);
        TextView dfixed_rateofdescription = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_rateofdescription);
        TextView dfixed_purchasevalue = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_purchasevalue);
        TextView dfixed_salevalue = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_salevalue);
        TextView dfixed_total = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_total);
        Button edit = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_edit);

        Button delete = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_delete);
        farp=db.getFARDetails();
        /*List<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<farp.size();i++){
            //list.add(maap.get(i).getAsset_Name());
            farp=db.getFARDetails();
            //dfixed_AssetID.setText(farp.get(farp.size()).getAsset_ID());
            Log.v("___________________________", "farp.get(i).getAsset_ID()___________"+farp.get(i).getAsset_ID());
           // Log.v("___________________________", "farp.get(i).getAsset_ID()___________"+farp);
            //dfixed_AssetID.setText(farpojo.getAsset_ID());
            //Log.v("___________________________", "farpojo.getAsset_ID()___________"+farpojo.getAsset_ID());

        }*/

        List<Fixed_asset_register_pojo> f = db.getFARDetails();       
        //for(int i=0;i<farp.size();i++){
        for (Fixed_asset_register_pojo f1 : f) {



        dfixed_AssetID.setText(f1.getAsset_ID());
        Log.e("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL", "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"+f1.getAsset_ID());
        dfixed_AssetDescription.setText(sfixed_AssetDescription);
        dfixed_SuppliersName.setText(f1.getSupplier_Name());
        dfixed_Makemodelotherspec.setText(f1.getModel_Specifications());
        dfixed_PO_no.setText(f1.getPurchase_Order_No());
        dfixed_PO_Date.setText(f1.getPurchase_Order_Date());
        dfixed_Bill_No.setText(f1.getBill_No());
        dfixed_qty.setText(f1.getQuantity());
        dfixed_Dateputtouse.setText(f1.getDate_Put_To_Use());
        dfixed_rateofdescription.setText(f1.getRate_Of_Depreciation());
        dfixed_purchasevalue.setText(f1.getPurchase_Amount());
        dfixed_salevalue.setText(f1.getSale_Amount());
        dfixed_total.setText(f1.getTotal_Amount());
        }

        ll.addView(child);
        linearLayout.addView(ll);

      }
```

i want to display all the rows in database table.but it is displaying in logcat and in device it is showing only last row in table.so please help me.
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Its showing in log cat because the loop is working fine but when you set the value on textview its replacing the old value to current and at last its showing only the last row values. for showing all the row values you should use other view like list view.

Comment: but to that textviews i have to set these db values and dynamically row should be create for each record

Comment: You should better use [ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)for this scenario. You can also find a quick view of ListView example [here.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)

Comment: then how i set values to particular heading

Comment: ya i understood but how i add according to my code. i had many textviews see almost 7 to 10.in respect to them it should display at below it data of database

Comment: what exactly you want to show . add any screenshot .

Comment: see in my screen at last only one row is displayed but i want all the rows to be display.

Comment: Simply Add listview below in your layout and create custom list with textviews and buttons.

Comment: how once show sample i am new to this

Comment: [custom listview](http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)  see this. May be useful for you

Comment: ok priyanka but how to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code is to get all the list in database.it works for me.

```
          public void dynamicLayout(String sfixed_AssetDescription ) {
        List<Fixed_asset_register_pojo> f = db.getFARDetails();      
        for (Fixed_asset_register_pojo f1 : f) {

            View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fixed_asset_dlayout, null);

                TextView dfixed_AssetID = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_AssetID);
                TextView dfixed_AssetDescription = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_AssetDescription);
                TextView dfixed_SuppliersName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_SuppliersName);
                TextView dfixed_Makemodelotherspec = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_Makemodelotherspec);
                TextView dfixed_PO_no = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_PO_no);
                TextView dfixed_PO_Date = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_PO_Date);
                TextView dfixed_Bill_No = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_Bill_No);
                TextView dfixed_qty = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_qty);
                TextView dfixed_Dateputtouse = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_Dateputtouse);
                TextView dfixed_rateofdescription = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_rateofdescription);
                TextView dfixed_purchasevalue = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_purchasevalue);
                TextView dfixed_salevalue = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_salevalue);
                TextView dfixed_total = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_total);

                Button edit = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_edit);

                Button delete = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.dfixed_delete);

                dfixed_AssetID.setText(f1.getAsset_ID());
                Log.e("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL",
                                "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" + f1.getAsset_ID());
                dfixed_AssetDescription.setText(sfixed_AssetDescription);
                dfixed_SuppliersName.setText(f1.getSupplier_Name());
                dfixed_Makemodelotherspec.setText(f1.getModel_Specifications());
                dfixed_PO_no.setText(f1.getPurchase_Order_No());
                dfixed_PO_Date.setText(f1.getPurchase_Order_Date());
                dfixed_Bill_No.setText(f1.getBill_No());
                dfixed_qty.setText(f1.getQuantity());
                dfixed_Dateputtouse.setText(f1.getDate_Put_To_Use());
                dfixed_rateofdescription.setText(f1.getRate_Of_Depreciation());
                dfixed_purchasevalue.setText(f1.getPurchase_Amount());
                dfixed_salevalue.setText(f1.getSale_Amount());
                dfixed_total.setText(f1.getTotal_Amount());
                linearLayout.addView(child);
        }
```